# c# Remote ip address

Tags: c#, sockets, dns, wifi, remote-server

i was working on c# app chatting on local network so that the computers clients and server connected to the same router

i have computer A and computer B 
in computer A i tried

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    namespace ConsoleApp3
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                IPAddress[]ips= Dns.GetHostAddresses("Server Name");
                for (int i = 0; i < ips.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ips[i].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so that B is the sever 
then i get this output

```
fe80::c199:7c21:1a54:f326%2
fe80::94a5:59a1:bb70:3cd9%23
fe80::a150:7e47:ee9c:5194%20
192.168.40.1
192.168.133.1
192.168.1.8
Press any key to continue . . .
```

i got 6 different ips
first 3 ip v6 and the second 3 are ip v4
there is addresses for vmware and lan and wifi
i know that the last one is the WIFI interface ip by typing ipconfig on cmd 
but i want this to be automatically
how to know what is the ip address of server Wifi interface ?

Comment: If you know both machines are in the same network, you could check computer A IP addresses and choose the one from machine B that matches the same network

Comment: If you want to get the IP of the interface that connects to a particular IP, [check it through UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376368/529282). But usually you don't need to manually check and input them, just [broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091537/how-to-make-server-client-autodiscover-over-a-lan) on the lan.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces?view=netframework-4.8). You can browse all of the adapters, find the one you want, and retrieve the network information you need there.