# Connect to a server without knowing ip c#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I have a client-server thing where I am the server and the clients need to connect to me. But the ips on the network change all the time so its not really reliable to hardcode it in the program. How would i go about doing this? Thanks for any answers

Comment: If you could only use names instead of numbers... oh wait - YOU CAN! :-D

Comment: Thats the thing i can't really use a dns on the network

Comment: is this LAN? WAN? would UDP broadcast be an option, or does it need to be targetted?

Comment: Maybe using NETBIOS names?

Comment: I assume you need the "address" of the server and not the ones of the clients., am I right?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes it is a LAN. But it would need to be tcp

Comment: @Stefan Yes i need the address of the server

Comment: Ok, normally you do this by hostname. If somehow you can't because ... some dark mysterious reason... you can fix the IP of the server.

Comment: @Webbanditten I can't really use NETBIOS either. Men tak for svaret :)

Comment: Can you try this one?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852781/c-sharp-how-to-do-network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast

Comment: @Stefan Thanks this is better than the solution I found :). And it was just an idea where I could have an external server where the ip could be static and it would contact that for the ip but this is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UDP to respond first request of the client with TCP ip details to connect server ,
Every client request must connect first time with the UDP then its establish the TCP connection

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I've found a solution.