# Is there a good replacement for WCF UDP Discovery in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, service-discovery, asp.net-core-2.1, ws-discovery

I am looking for UDP service discovery functionality in ASP.NET Core.  This functionality is available in .NET Framework WCF via System.ServiceModel.Discovery (e.g., UdpDiscoveryEndpoint that uses WS-Discovery).

The intended result is to allow clients on a LAN to discover an ASP.NET Core WebAPI without needing to know the server's name/IP and port.

I see some service discovery frameworks available like Consul, but they don't seem to support UDP broadcasts.

I could write my own using code similar to the solution in [How to do Network discovery using UDP broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852781/how-to-do-network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast), but I have to question whether something better is available already.

Comment: You are aware udp without realys only works in VERY Limited scenarios. LAN is not even one - a LAN can do routing (and does in any sane larger company). This is one reason they fell out of use.

Comment: It's potentially coming in v3 https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/211

Answer (score 0):

Could be using Ocelot, http://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/servicediscovery.html

An example of how this could potentially be implemented can be found here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-api-gateway-using-ocelot-in-asp-net-core-service-discoveryeureka/

Comment: It looks like Ocelot leverages Consul or Eureka.  Both of these solutions still require you to know the host name of the discovery registry server.  I was looking for a way to discover services without this piece of info.